# MATLAB: pdepe boundary function

Tags: matlab

Why did I get an error like **''Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. Error in bcfcn (line 7) qr = Ds*J(t,1)''** when I used pdepe matlab solver to solve diffusion equation on spherical coordinate. The Ds is just an constant but J is actually a vector with respect to time which has both very large positive and negative integers. I cannot change these value to all positive since it is a boundary condition given.

Is that because I need to change the J vector to some function with respect to time?? Actually I have tried to change all J to positive to figure out how does it work, but it doesn't work either.

Thank you very much!
Lu

Comment: Sry the title is supposed to be MATLAB: pdepe boundary function

Comment: What data type is t in J(t,1)? Is it a valid type for a subscript? Another possibility is you used a Matlab function name as a variable assignment somewhere.

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is it possible, that `t` has a zero or negative value under some circumstances?

Comment: Thank you paisanco, Sardar_Usama and  bushmills. I already solved this problem by adding '' interp1(1:60, J(:,1), t, 'linear', 'extrap')''. But I am really confused that why is the time t requested by pdepe is not consistent with the timespan I set in the main function?